# ASK Deploy Error: Invalid URL Info

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

My invocation of the `ask deploy` command failed because of the following error:

```
$ ask deploy
[Error]: Invalid url info.
Cannot find valid lambda function with the given name, nor find sourceDir as codebase path to create lambda function.
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

The `.aws/config` file will look something like below. If you change the endpoint uri to match the lambda function ARN that you have in `skill.json`, the skill should deploy using `ask deploy`

```
{
  "deploy_settings": {
    "default": {
      "skill_id": "",
      "was_cloned": false,
      "merge": {
        "manifest": {
          "apis": {
            "custom": {
              "endpoint": {
                "uri": "<lambda-arn-here>"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "in_skill_products": []
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For my problem, the solution was to clone my repository into a new directory and deploy from there. For example:

```
$ ask clone --skill-id <<MY_SKILL_ID>>
-------------------- Clone Skill Project --------------------
Project directory for mySkill created at
    ./mySkill

Skill schema for movie-go created at
    ./mySkill/skill.json

Skill model for en-US created at
    ./mySkill/models/en-US.json

Downloading Lambda functions...
    arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:876716374418:function:ask-custom-mySkill-default download finished.
$ cd mySkill/
$ ask deploy
This skill project was cloned from a pre-existing skill. Deploying this project will
  - Update skill metadata (skill.json)
  - Update interaction model (models/*.json)
  - Deploy the Lambda function(s) in ./lambda/*
? Do you want to proceed with the above deployments? Yes
-------------------- Update Skill Project --------------------
Skill Id: <<MY_SKILL_ID>>
Skill deployment finished.
Model deployment finished.
Lambda deployment finished.
```

I found this solution suggested in a comment on [this intro to ASK CLI video](https://ru-clip.com/video/p-zlSdixCZ4/introduction-to-the-alexa-skills-kit-cli-ask-cli.html).